# xcode4 : How to use "git repository" to share same project with multiple users on different computer?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

Xcode4's new feature "git repository" is good feature. But I am confuse with it.

Does it allow check-in and check-out functionality ?

Does it allow other user to modify same file if someone already modifying it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, git is a full version control system (VCS). There are many great resources for learning about git such as all of the resources listed in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide).

Comment: Does it allow to check-in & check-out ?

Comment: @Devang: Why not visit git-scm.com and read about the features and basic commands there, rather than asking SO to repeat them here?