# Xcode4 : How do I enable following feature of Xcode4?

Tags: git, ios4, xcode4

I want to enable "Check-out" feature of "git local repository".

As shown in following image.

[image]

How do I enable that?

Comment: Did you try to select an entry and see if the checkout icon becomes then active?

Comment: Yes i have tried that. But its not working !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode4 : How to use "git repository" to share same project with multiple users on different computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026455/xcode4-how-to-use-git-repository-to-share-same-project-with-multiple-users-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Checkout button you showed is for Subversion repositories, not git repositories. It's used to check files out of Subversion repositories.

What you probably are asking is how to switch branches from Xcode. Your screenshot is what appears when you click the Branches folder for a repository. Below that folder is another folder, which probably matches your project name. Select that folder. You should see a Switch Branch button at the bottom of the Organizer. Click that button to switch branches.